# C++ equivalent of C99 extern inline __attribute__((always_inline))

Tags: c++, linker, inline, c99, extern

Hi,

I read [the wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inline_function#C99) then I realized "extern inline" is different between C99 and C++.

For example:

foo.cpp

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>

extern inline __attribute__((always_inline))
void test1(int b) {
    if (b) {
        printf("foo");
    }
}

void test2() {
    test1(0);
}
```

main.cpp

```cpp
void test1(int);
void test2();

int main() {
    test1(0);
    test2();
}
```

I can compile and link them by using '-xc -std=c99' for g++ and clang++.

However, I do need a C++ equivalent of this, any idea?

Thank you very much.

P.S. The current workaround is using a wrapper function, which is not elegant.

Comment: `__attribute__((always_inline))` is not standard at all (neither C or C++). Just remove the `extern inline`. What is the point of it supposed to be here anyway (in C or C++)?

Comment: Yes, what's your use-case for this?  Just let the compiler / optimiser do its stuff.

Comment: Just remove the extern for C++?

Comment: Thanks. The code was extremely simplified so it might be not that clear about the purpose. To make long story short, the motivation is that if test1 is used in the same translation unit, it needs to be inlined.